# Weird Behavior when wrapping redis-py

Tags: python-3.x, redis, redis-py

If I create a redis-py object directly, I get the following:

```py
>>> r = redis.Redis(host='192.168.1.xxx', port=xxxx, decode_responses=True)
>>> r.ping()
True
```

However, if I create a convenience wrapper as follows, I get an error (see below). Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

Here is the convenience wrapper with numerous methods. Only the `__init__` is needed.

```py
import redis


class RedisCommunication:
    def __init__(self, host=None, port=None):
        self.REDIS_HOST = '192.168.1.xxx'
        self.REDIS_PORT = xxxx

        try:
            self.rc = redis.Redis(
                host=self.REDIS_HOST,
                port=self.REDIS_PORT,
                db=0,
                decode_responses=True)
        except redis.ConnectionError:
            exit(1)

# import the above and run the following
>>> redcom = RedisCommunication()
>>> redcom.rc.ping()
```

The internal structure of redcom.rc and r above appears identical. I would expect `redcom.rc.ping()` to yield `True`. But instead I get the following:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/mambaforge/base/envs/wadjet-backend-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 699, in connect
    sock = self.retry.call_with_retry(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/mambaforge/base/envs/wadjet-backend-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 46, in call_with_retry
    return do()
           ^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/mambaforge/base/envs/wadjet-backend-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 700, in <lambda>
    lambda: self._connect(), lambda error: self.disconnect(error)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/mambaforge/base/envs/wadjet-backend-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1002, in _connect
    raise err
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/mambaforge/base/envs/wadjet-backend-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 990, in _connect
    sock.connect(socket_address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/231.9011.38/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
           ^^^^^^
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/mambaforge/base/envs/wadjet-backend-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 1205, in ping
    return self.execute_command("PING", **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/mambaforge/base/envs/wadjet-backend-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1266, in execute_command
    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/mambaforge/base/envs/wadjet-backend-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1457, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/mambaforge/base/envs/wadjet-backend-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 705, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 61 connecting to 192.168.1.xxx:xxxx. Connection refused.
```

Comment: are you sure, you are passing correct parameters? This may be because of some typo. Also, you need not necessarily have parameters like `host` and `port` in the __init__, if you are not using them. Also you shouldn't use `exit(1)`, this will close the python program, unless thats what you want. Instead you should raise an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It is definitely not a typo. I understand that exit closes the program – the db connection is essential to program operation.

Answer (score 0):

What I didn't mention in the original post: I'm using a `StrEnum` and an `IntEnum`. Apparently redis-py can't deal with these.

Comment: Can't deal with dataclasses either.

Comment: So this got a lot weirder. If I leave out port, `redis-py` defaults to 6397 and works with a dataclass str for the IP address.

However, if I pass in this via a dataclass, it chokes. This smells like a bug. Any thought?